# How to shrink a XFS filesystem?

Tags: rhel, lvm, disk

We have a RHEL 7 server with 2 disks (`sda` and `sdb`). Our `/`, `/var/log` and `swap` are on `sda`, `/var` is on `sdb`. We use LVM and XFS.

`sda` is too big (160 GB) and we would like to shrink it to 40 GB. We can then use the free 120 GB to extend `sdb`.

```
[root@foo ~]# pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  rhel      lvm2 a--  134.77g 9.77g
  /dev/sdb1  vg_var    lvm2 a--  200.00g    0


[root@foo ~]# lvs
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root      rhel      -wi-ao---- 117.19g
  swap      rhel      -wi-ao----   3.91g
  var_log   rhel      -wi-ao----   3.91g
  lv_var    vg_var    -wi-ao---- 200.00g

[root@foo ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3235298e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   419430399   209714176   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sda: 161.1 GB, 161061273600 bytes, 314572800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0009b153

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048   283656191   141315072   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-root: 125.8 GB, 125829120000 bytes, 245760000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-swap: 4194 MB, 4194304000 bytes, 8192000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_var-lv_var: 214.7 GB, 214744170496 bytes, 419422208 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-var_log: 4194 MB, 4194304000 bytes, 8192000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

How can we safely achieve this? I have tried this with a test machine, but it failed:

1. Add a new disk
2. Create an LVM partition, pvcreate and add a new LV on it.
3. Boot with rescue disk
4. Mount `sda` to `/mnt/sysimage` and mount the LV of the new disk to `/mnt/sdb`
5. `cp -ax /mnt/sysimage/* /mnt/sdb`
6. Update `/mnt/sysimage/etc/fstab` to use `/dev/mapper/rhel-lv_root`
7. Finally the reboot fails due to `INT18 boot failure`

Comment: Question does not make sense.  /dev/sda and /dev/sdb are hard disks.  Their size is determined by how they are manufactured and can not be changed.

Comment: @psusi Theoretically you can have a hard disk without a partition table which you then use like a single partition but I doubt that this what OP is doing here.

Comment: @psusi If the machine is a VM then /dev/sd[ab] could very well be resizeable, because they'd be files on the host system

Answer (score 23):

> Currently [2019] XFS Filesystems can't be shrunk.

http://xfs.org/index.php/Shrinking_Support

This is what is said on RH website:

- It is currently not possible to reduce the size of a partition or logical volume with the xfs filesystem. If you are interested in this functionality please contact Red Hat support and reference Red Hat bugzilla 1062667, and provide your use-case for needing XFS reduction / shrinking.
- As a possible workaround in some environments, thin provisioned LVM volumes can be considered as an additional layer below the XFS filesystem.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/540013

Comment: More details for the workaround would be very welcome. The link to redhat.com is not accessible for non-subscribers.

Comment: @JonasKongslund I also can't read it, but a "thinly provisioned" device, such as on LVM (there are also devices based of of qcow files) will not store data that has been discarded by the filesystem. So you can have a massive filesystem size (many terabytes), and using the fstrim command, you can discard the blocks that aren't used. Then, your underlying thin storage in turn, does not use that space. So from the perspective of XFS the filesystem is not shrunk, but from the perspective of the underlying storage device it's using less space. You can in theory copy an XFS FS off a device to a thin

Comment: What a worthless answer. Yea, most of us can look up RHEL support as well. Thanks for nothing. The right answer is probably creating a new volume and then rsyching on to it, and remember NOT to use XFS, because it doesn't support basic FS functionality.

Comment: "provide your use-case for needing XFS reduction / shrinking." <- this sounds exactly like a PR suicide