Reducing the / mount point size in Redhat Enterprise Linux 9
I want to re-allocated some of the storage space in the / mount point for other mount points like /opt and /tmp. The filesystem is formated in xfs file system so I was not able to use lvreduce or resize2fs commands to reduce the root logical volume. I cannot unmount it as the / is used by the system. I then restarted it using the cd-rom without mounting the filesystem. The device was shown in the lsblk as below.\

And, lvreduce command fails with the error below and I couldn't find any reference online as well

Thanks!

You would need to activate the VG (or at least the appropriate LV(s)) first, using vgchange -ay or lvchange. But as Romeo Ninov says in the answer below, there seems to be no production-grade XFS filesystem shrinking tool in existence yet. There are development versions, but I would not recommend them in production use unless you know for sure that the missing bits of functionality are not needed in your specific case... and evaluating that requires some in-depth knowledge on XFS which I don't have.

If the filesystem is XFS forget about shrinking. The only way (I know) is to make backup, destroy and recreate again.
And the command about manage the size of XFS filesystem is xfs_growfs from package xfsprogs

Shrinking XFS has been a sore issue for over a decade. See for example
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279502/how-to-shrink-a-xfs-filesystem
https://serverfault.com/questions/81262/how-can-you-shrink-an-xfs-filesystem
